# Android. how can I determine how long a user has been inactive?

Tags: android

I have a wizard app where user goes thru 8-10 activities but might drop off at any point.  I need to detect user inactivity somehow, which could occur on any of the activities.  What is the best way to capture and detect his.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd persist (using one of the recommended methods, ie SharedPreferences, SQLite, file etc) a timestamp and activity identifier (so you know which one they dropped off on) that you can grab later.  Depending on how you define "inactivity" this should probably be set in either `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()`.

Full activity lifecycle link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: would you care to elaborate on the solution?  I am not so concerned about which activity was the location of the inactivity, its just that they could be on any activity when they become inactive, and I need a way to set a timeout on inactivity.

Comment: The best way to check for inactivity I think would be when one of the above mentioned methods is called (doing something like a timeout on the last time the user touched the screen might be possible, but wouldn't be 100% accurate).  And if you don't want to add the same thing to all of your activities, create an Activity subclass that overrides one of the above methods that then all your Activities inherit from.

Does that help?